# How to create a simple video gallery in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want create a simple html video gallery in html, where many images show in tables and when we click on any then it play related video. I search but not found something. Is it not possible?

I tried this code:

```
   <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf">
  </object>
</video>
```

but how link this video with any image when we click on that image, video plays.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not providing full HTML markup, I'll place the image right before 
the video as an example:

```
<img class="galleryImg" src="your image src here" /> 
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
        <embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf">
    </object>
</video>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('img.galleryImg').each(function() {
    $(this).next().get(0).play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try in w3schools has the follow [Live Preview](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_video_html5_4)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
<embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf">
</object>
</video>
```

You can create a table like http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp and then remove, embed the images with your youtube video. So that i will play the video once you click it.

However w3layouts provide gallery template what you expect in easy way you can download it from [here.](http://w3layouts.com/videostube-video-gallery-mobile-website-template)